# Access first responder of MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm interested in doing something similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690279/set-first-responder-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller), however the component subviews of `MFMessageComposeViewController` are a much different than `MFMailComposeViewController`.

I figured out how to set focus to the input that let's you to type your message text by simply calling `setRecipients:` with an array containing a blank NSString.  However, I'd like to paste non-text from the pasteBoard into the input, so I can't simply use `setBody:`.

**Problem:**
What I need to do is get a reference to the actual text field that is the current first responder for my MFMessageComposeViewController.  This way, I have a "sender" I can pass to UIPasteboard's `paste:` method. The problem is, I can't seem to walk the subview hierarchy the same way as MFMailComposeViewController, so I can't find out which view is first responder.

I've even [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/how-do-i-legally-get-the-current-first-responder-on-the-screen-on-an-iphone), but the view is always returned as nil if I do a `[myMessageVC.view findFirstResponder]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word of caution, you're not supposed to have your hands inside that view. Apple will refuse your app for doing so. You are only allowed to set the body and recipients.

> Important The message composition interface itself is not customizable
>   and must not be modified by your application. In **addition, after
>   presenting the interface, your application is unable to make further
>   changes to the SMS content**. The user can edit the content using the
>   interface, but **programmatic changes are ignored**. Thus, you must set
>   the values of content fields, if desired, before presenting the
>   interface

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'll do without :(  Look like the thing doesn't even share the generalPasteboard either! So I can't even instruct my users to paste an image I've set in the pasteboard :(