# Autofocus on subject when opening MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is there a way to autofocus the subject field when opening MFMailComposeViewController? I did find one post on this ([Set First Responder in MFMailComposeViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690279/set-first-responder-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)) but it seems to be deprecated.